# Docker with postgresql in flask web application (part 2)

Tags: postgresql, docker, flask, sqlalchemy

I am building a Flask application in Python. I'm using SQLAlchemy to connect to PostgreSQL.

In the flask application, I'm using this to connect SQLAlchemy to PostgreSQL

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:[mypassword]@db:5432/employee-manager-db')
```

And this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    links:
      - db:db
    depends_on:
      - pgadmin

  db:
    image: postgres:14.5
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql
    hostname: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: [mypassword]
      POSTGRES_DB: employee-manager-db

  pgadmin:
    image: 'dpage/pgadmin4'
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: [myemail]
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: [mypassword]
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I can do "docker build -t employee-manager ." to build the image. However, when I do "docker run -p 5000:5000 employee-manager" to run the image, I get an error saying

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Try again
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your containers are on different networks and that is why they don't see each other.

When you run `docker-compose up`, docker-compose creates a separate network and puts all the services defined inside docker-compose.yml on that network. You can see that with `docker network ls`.

When you run a container with `docker run`, it is attached to the default bridge network, which is isolated from other networks.

There are several ways to fix this, but this one will serve you in many other scenarios:

Run `docker container ls` and identify the name or ID of the `db` container that was started with `docker-compose`

Then run your container with:

```
# ID_or_name from the previous point
docker run -p 5000:5000 --network container:<ID_or_name> employee-manager
```

This attached the new container to the same network as your database container.

Other ways include creating a network manually and defining that network as default in the docker-compose.yml. Then you can use `docker run --network <network_name> ...` to attach other containers to that network.

Comment: It'd be better to use `docker network ls` to find the name of the network (probably `directoryname_default`) and use that name (`docker run --net directoryname_default`).  `--net container:...` is a pretty unusual setup.

Comment: that's actually not such a god idea @DavidMaze. As you mentioned the network name would be `directoryname_default` so if you have more docker-compose setups running on the same machine in different paths but the same directory, you wouldn't know which one to pick. If you really want to go clever about it, then you should still investigate the settings of the container: `docker inspect <container_name_or_id> --format='{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks}}'`. This will give you the network name that you then can use. This is what `--net container:...`  does under the hood anyway.

Answer (score -1):

`docker run` doesn't read any of the information in the `docker-compose.yml` file, and it doesn't see things like the Docker network that Compose automatically creates.

In your case you already have the service fully-defined in the `docker-compose.yml` file, so you can use Compose commands to build and restart it

```bash
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d # will delete and recreate changed containers
```

(If the name of the image is important to you – maybe you're pushing to a registry – you can specify `image:` alongside `build:`.  `links:` are obsolete and you should remove them.  I'd also avoid replacing the image's content with `volumes:`, since this misses any setup or modification that's done in the Dockerfile and it means you're running untested code if you ever deploy the image without the mount.)

Comment: Your Dockerfile will usually have a line like `COPY . .` to copy the current source tree into the image, and if you have that, yes, you can just remove the `volumes:` section.